# Positioning something at the bottom but alignParentBottom=true isn't having any effect

Tags: android, xml, admob

I am working on an android app, and I am making a layout which has a series of edittexts and also contains adverts provided by admob.

For the advert, I want it fixed to to the bottom of the screen, however, it stays floating in the middle, just underneath the bottom of the main content.

On the admob adview, I've put the `alignParentBottom=true` but it doesn't seem to have worked.

Below is a copy of the XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <EditText android:id="@+id/newDB_txtConnectionName"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Database Connection Name"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:inputType="textNoSuggestions" />
    <EditText android:id="@+id/newDB_txtServer"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Server"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:inputType="textNoSuggestions" />
    <EditText android:id="@+id/newDB_txtUsername"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Username"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:inputType="textNoSuggestions" />
    <EditText android:id="@+id/newDB_txtPassword"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Password"
        android:password="true"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:inputType="textNoSuggestions" />
    <EditText android:id="@+id/newDB_txtDatabase"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Database"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:inputType="textNoSuggestions" />
    <EditText android:id="@+id/newDB_txtPort"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:maxLength="4"
        android:hint="Port"
        android:text="3306"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:inputType="textNoSuggestions"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="Leave database blank to connect to any database on this server" />
    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/buttonContainer"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        style="?android:attr/buttonBarStyle"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">
        <Button android:id="@+id/newDB_btnTest"
            android:layout_width="0dp" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Test Connection"
            style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle" />
        <Button android:id="@+id/newDB_btnCreate"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Create"
            android:enabled="false"
            style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle" />
    </LinearLayout>
        <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView android:id="@+id/adView"
             android:layout_width="fill_parent"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_gravity="center"
             ads:adUnitId="MY_PUBLISHER_ID"
             ads:adSize="BANNER"
             android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>
</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 1):

alignParentBottom is not valid in LinearLayout, use RelativeLayout if you want to use that flag

Comment: Thanks, when I change the LinearLayout to a RelativeLayout, everything bunches at the top of the screen, everything is overlapping each other at the top of the screen

Comment: Ok, you can replace android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" with android:layout_gravity="bottom", then no need to change to RelativeLayout

Comment: Still no luck, still floats just underneath the bottom of the main GUI, not the bottom of the screen

Comment: Try adding android:fillViewport="true" to ScrollView and android:layout_weight="1" to the buttonContainer LinearLayout. Then add android:layout_gravity="bottom" to the AdView (note that is already at center, replace it for bottom)

Comment: The advert is at the bottom, however, the button container now grows to the fill the space, so the buttons become huge and the vertical separation line of the container goes all the way to the bottom the screen as well

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a LinearLayout then you need to tel something to expand to fill the unused space. You do that by giving the item that you want to expand **layout_weight="1"**. Eg

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <EditText android:id="@+id/newDB_txtConnectionName"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Database Connection Name"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:inputType="textNoSuggestions" />
    < lots more EditTexts />
    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/buttonContainer"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        style="?android:attr/buttonBarStyle"
        **android:layout_weight="1"**>
        <Some Buttons/>
    </LinearLayout>
        <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView android:id="@+id/adView"
             android:layout_width="fill_parent"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_gravity="center"
             ads:adUnitId="MY_PUBLISHER_ID"
             ads:adSize="BANNER"
</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Thanks but unfortunately made no difference

Comment: Sorry, I missed the fact that you have **layout_gravity="center"** for the AdView. Remove that too.

Comment: Thanks, the advert is positioned to the bottom but because the button container is filling the unused space, the vertical line of the button separator goes to the bottom as well which looks a bit messy. I want the button container to just be the height of the buttons

Comment: Well you need **something** to fill the space. If you don't want any of your existing Views to fill the unused space then I suggest you create a new View (blank TextView or empty LinearLayout perhaps), and give it **layout_weight="1"** instead of buttonContainer.  Suggest you also read http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html